# Should we re-open the Spotify blacklist question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

I asked this question last night:

https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/what-artists-are-not-available-on-spotify

It's something I've always wondered: what am I missing out on now that Spotify is my primary music source. There are a couple articles on this topic out there on the internet, but most of them are stale, they aren't editable by the community, and none of them is comprehensive.

I know we frown upon lists at Stack Exchange. But we do make exceptions when they provide value to the world at large. I think this is an exceptional case and I hope you choose to re-open the question.

Comment: BTW, I realize I may have cleared a flag of my own creation on the post in question. I didn't realize my power and I didn't mean to do that.

Answer (score 8):

More to thee point, that question is simply impossible to answer. There are quite literally millions of artists that are not on Spotify. My band isn't. Is yours?

I assume that what you're asking is "what *well known* artists are not on Spotify", and weren't actually expecting a list that included myself, my mate's band or that nice little group I once heard in a seedy bar in Barcelona 5 years ago. Even so, what defines a "well known" artist? How could we know where to draw the line? Should we list all artists from Swaziland who are not there? How about those from Finland who only play in local bars?

Your question is asking for an enormous and constantly changing list. I see nothing exceptional apart from its being a particularly long and impossible to maintain, let alone make comprehensive, list. Such questions are both not useful and off topic across the entire SE network.

Comment: Good points, terdon.

Answer (score 5):

StackOverflow isn't really set up to handle "list questions", which is why they're discouraged.  There's no way to keep order, and who will be responsible for updating the answers when a band decides to change their mind?  What about new releases?  Who's updating this list every Tuesday when new discs drop?

I agree that it's a nice list to have, but I don't really think it will work on this site.

Comment: True, Stack Overflow isn't, but this isn't Stack Overflow. I figured maybe an upstart site like this wouldn't be afraid to experiment a little, especially when the use case seems so apt. And of course nobody is responsible for updating anything. What's great about this platform is that anyone _can_.

Comment: So, we're supposed to leave potentially incorrect answers up, on the hopes that someone will come around and update it?  No.  That's not how the Stack Exchange network works.

Comment: It's a valid concern if you think this question will considerably increase the mod workload. But still, this is all hypothetical.

Comment: @samthebrand  so you are suggesting we allow a question that has an infinite number of answers, will be impossible  to maintain, and attract potential spam?

Comment: @Dom when you put it that way, it does sound dangerous! But yeah. I think that can explain a few thousand list-like questions found across the network that perform just fine and don't put undue burden on mods. All that said... I'm mostly just hoping you give this question a shot.

Comment: @samthebrand We have experimented with list questions on “upstart” sites. The conclusion is that they don't work. (Look at the deleted questions from the first couple of weeks of [scifi.se], for instance.) It's not specific to Stack Overflow. When the experiment has failed again and again and again, doing it yet over again is no longer science, it's a waste of time.

Comment: @Gilles yeah, there were a lot of list questions asked on Sci-Fi in the early days, and a lot of them [were closed](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/391777/closed-questions) (that's only the undeleted ones). But those list questions had no or very little practical value - why & to whom is it valuable to know "what books include a developed alien language?" The list question I posted is valuable to me, and I know many others. I think this changes the risk / benefit profile of letting the question live.

Comment: @samthebrand Uh? A list of books that include a developed alien language is useful to people who like reading books with alien languages, in exactly the same way that your question is useful to people who use Spotify to discover artists and worry about what they could be missing.

Comment: @Gilles well maybe that question shouldn't have been closed. Or maybe it should have. At least it was given a few days to live (though even that question wasn't given time to attract the spam that we're all afraid of). Anyway it's your community, you can do what you deem appropriate. It's just too bad we refuse to take tiny risks that could result in delivering lots of value to music listeners like me.

Comment: @samthebrand there is no value. A definitive list is impossible to compile. I use Spotify myself and can't imagine how an answer would go. Remember that there are hundreds of thousands (millions?) of little known artists around the world who are not on Spotify. How in the world could anyone give you a list? A much better question would be to ask for the list of artists who _are_ on Spotify. At least that one would have a defined end point.

Comment: would you consider protecting the question to prevent spam and so I can continue to curate the list? @dom

Comment: @samthebrand The spam is only one of many issues as I said in my post. Currently based on this meta discussion, there really isn't any support for reopening it besides yourself so there isn't a reason to reopen yet.

Answer (score 3):

There are a ton of issues with a question like this. Besides the obvious issue that it is a lot of information to keep track of and we're not going to be able to guarantee it's up to date due to new albums constantly being released and new artist coming onto the scene, a question like this **will** attract spam.

As a musician, I work with bands that have there own album that would love to be on a service like Spotify. I guarantee at least a few artists will take advantage of a question like this to get their albums out there and noticed and we won't be able to tell the difference most of the time.

Comment: I think the spam concern is valid, but really it's a boogie man that we won't know exists until we know. I've got my name on the question, so I'm notified of any new answers. I'm happy to patrol it myself.

Comment: @samthebrand every SE attracts spam and this one is no different and this question welcome it with open arms. I know that is not your intent,  but it's what will happen.

Comment: probably. But that's what happens when you create attractive things: stuff sticks, some of it's bad. As mentioned, I'm happy to keep an eye on the question and keep it clean.

Answer (score -2):

May have to envoke blacklist override.

What is this about anyway?
Some sort of deprecation list?
Worse? I can only imagine.

So, yeah reminds me I gotta download Spotify again - darn reformat

And this concludes yet another edition of Masterpiece Theatre.
I'm your host, Host McHostington.

Good Night.

---

[(cue theme)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZ8QVKOWbPU)

[image]